# Populate list with instantiated classes dynamically with Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an abstract class and all classes in some package derive from it. Is there a way to create a list that dynamically instantiates all these classes that reside in some package when using Kotlin on Android?

Here is an example:

- com.example.service

  - BaseService
  - com.example.service.emailservice

    - GmailService
    - OutlookService

All classes in com.example.service.emailservice derive from BaseService abstract class that resides in com.example.service. I want to create a list that contains GmailService and OutlookService objects. I could instantiate them manually and add them to a list, but in future I may add new service, lets say YandexService, which should appear in list too. This requires manual instantiation again. Is there a way to automatically instantiate classes that reside in some package?

Comment: please share some code, and for more help code you want to do your job

Comment: I can't really share any code since I'm asking for a way to do it differently. It's not like the code isn't working. I can just provide code for manual instantiation, but I'm asking how to do it the other way. I can do manual instantiation like this: ListOf(GmalService(), OutlookService(), YandexService()), but I don't want to do it this way, so I am asking for a different, more dynamic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mayor ways to do it.

The first one - easier and dirtier one called Reflection.
You may find a lot of examples in java. Not so much in Kotlin though, but from what I have read [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/index.html) it is more than possible. 
Usage of Reflection though, is not recommended in production, and generally considered as a bad approach to fulfill something.

The second way is Annotation Processors - this way is way harder. It is considered a clean way to do such tasks though and it is a general standard for code generating techniques. This way you can do all kinds of magic if you put your mind to it. [Here](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/generating-code-via-annotations-in-kotlin) is nice article about how to do it.

Generally I would recommend to use semiautomatic approach.

For example:
In your base service with init method

```
abstract class BaseService {

     abstract fun init(): BaseService

}
```

Make all your services implement this BaseService

```
class Service : BaseService() {

     override fun init(): BaseService {
         return Service()
     }

}
...
```

And then just create a list of classes

```
val services = listOf(Service(), Service1(), Service2())
```

and to init them do

```
services.forEach { it.init() }
```

This is not very different from what you have and may require some logical and architectural changes in your Services and App overall, but it won't be dirty and it won't require tremendous learning curve and time expenses.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use [this library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) 
add to `gradle.build`

`implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11'`

then in your package `com.example.service` create a class from where you will be creating your Services, let's call it `ServiceFactory` here is implementation:

```
package com.example.service

import org.reflections.Reflections

class ServiceFactory {
    init {
        val reflections = Reflections(javaClass.`package`.name)
        val subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(BaseService::class.java)
        val yourServices = subTypes.map { it.getConstructor().newInstance() }
        yourServices.forEach { println(it.javaClass.name) }
    }
}


fun main() {
    ServiceFactory()
}
```

out:

```
com.example.service.emailservice.OutlookService
com.example.service.emailservice.GmailService
```

Something you were looking for ?

EDIT: of course you can instantiate this services from different place, but in that case you need to hardcode `Reflections("com.example.service")`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It seems that Reflections library doesn't work on Android.